# Can I go outside the airport if I'm flying transit, and if visa not required for my citizenship?

Tags: visas, transit, turkey, uzbek-citizens

I'm citizen of Uzbekistan, and I don't need visa for Turkey. And I'm flying transit 13 hours, can I go outside the airport for sometimes, holding my transit ticket?

Comment: if your layover is in the Istanbul airport, they will even give you a free tour of the city, or a hotel room!

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, Yes you can. Just make sure you get back to the airport before the flight.
If your flight is in one ticket, then you do not even need to pick up luggage and re-check it in (thanks to @jpatokal for the reminder). Just go out, enjoy your time :)

Comment: But what about the procedure?? Is it fine if I will take already 2 passenger ticket when I will be checking in 1 at time, and they will give me 2 tickets... Should I do something with this?